# WordPress, get_categories, taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have a very simple question that is not answered on WordPress Codex.

The get_categories() function get an option for taxonomies. What I like to ask is, can I pass more than one taxonomies like that:

```
get_categories(
    array(
        'taxonomies' => 'category,my_custom_taxonomy'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get_categories function only allows a string (1 taxonomy) to be entered for the taxonomy arg.

You can use [get_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) which allows an array of taxonomies.

```
$args = array( 'taxonomies' => array( 'tax_1', 'tax_2', 'tax_3') );

$categories = get_terms ( $args );

for each ( $categories as $cat ) :

  var_dump( $cat );

endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris ! I just had forget the function get_terms() ! xaxax :D Again thanks a lot.